# Symbol with class variable passed

Tags: ruby, symbols

I saw the following code:

```
controller.instance_variable_get(:@account)
```

What does `:@account` do? `@account` is an instance variable.  Does symbolizing here expand the value inside of `@account` and make it into a symbol with that value (i.e. `@account == 'message'` and `:@account` will create `:message`)? Or, is it a symbol such that `:@account.to_s == '@account'`?

Comment: `@account` is not a method, it's a variable.

Comment: Yes, `:@account` is "a symbol such that `:@account.to_s == '@account'`". You could have run that exact code in your console and answered your own question.

Comment: I didn't think about. I am still new to ruby and the console is foreign to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:@account` itself is a symbol literal. You need a way to refer to the name of the instance variable in question. The most straightforward way is to use a symbol or a string. That is what is happening.

Comment: what does that mean exactly? i found http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get that says you need to pass in the @account symbol there. So the :@account is like the latter option noted in my question?